# What is this yellow flower with thick curved petals?

Tags: identification, flowers, wildflowers

I took this photo a few years ago and the flower was found in the wild. It was all over the place but I haven't been able to find what the flower is called and where else it is found.

This was found in Assam, India.

[image: yellow flower wild]

Comment: Do the leaves in your pic belong this flower? How tall were the plants?

Comment: Hi, yes the leaves in the background belongs to the flower. The plants were nearly 5 to 6 feet.

Comment: I note the edit to the answer below (first sentence), and in that edit, the plant has been correctly identified as Senna (or Cassia) alata, sometimes called Candelabra tree or bush; the flowers in your pic haven't begun to open yet, see link here for image http://www.georgiavines.com/cart/index.php?main_page=product_info&products_id=957

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: Based on OP's comment about the leaves, it is possible, the tree is Senna alata

I believe this beautiful specimen is Cryptochilus lutea. Look it up online and see if that jogs your memory.

Were there green tendrils off to one side of the plant?

Do you have any other pictures?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the answer. 

Unfortunately it doesn't seem to be it. Aah, there were no tendrils. 

I don't have more pictures, but the leaves you see in the background belongs to the same plant, that could be of help. 

Thanks. It has been bugging me for over a year now haha.

Comment: Its not Cryptochilus, but it is Senna  alata...

Comment: Hi @SrihariYamanoor, I just looked up the name on Google and it appears to be Senna alata! :) Please add it as an answer so that I can mark it. Thanks.